# how to get what number is the letter in the word?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have this program:

```
word = input('enter word:')
letter = input('enter letter to find:')

y = word.find(letter)
print(y)
```

and it only print 0:

```
enter word:pythop
enter letter to find:p
0
>>>
```

so how can I get the position of both of this letter 'p' as it only recognise one of it? thanks

Comment: You've already got it. `y` is the index. `find()` function finds the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need a loop. If you only ever need to check for a single letter (not a substring), you can enumerate the characters of the word:

```
word = input('enter word:')
letter = input('enter letter to find:')

ys = [i for i, l in enumerate(word) if l == letter]
print(ys)
```

Answer (score 2):

You got it!  String position 0 is the first position in a string.

```
>>> 'pythop'.find('p')
0
>>> 'pythop'.find('y')
1
>>>
```

Comment: yes...but there are two p's there and it only recognises one...so how can I get both of it?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated my answer due to typo:**

I would do something like this:

```
word = input('enter word:')
letter = input('enter letter to find:')

y = [i for i in range(len(word)) if word.startswith(letter, i)]
print(y)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yeah..it helps..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use find with start and end positions. Here the docstring:

```
find(...)
    S.find(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int

    Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
    such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
    arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

    Return -1 on failure.
```